# Can't report a bug on for a project on Launchpad--What to do (e.g. Skype Wrapper)

Tags: skype, launchpad, bug-reporting, debian

I want to report a bug in `Skype Wrapper` [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper) but am not able to do it. Do I need to be a member to report a bug? I have a Launchpad account and I tried reporting it while logged in but I see no option to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those using Launchpad can use it for many things, or can choose only to use certain features. It appears to me that the group providing a PPA for *Skype Wrapper* only use Launchpad for hosting the packages in a PPA. Some projects may include a pointer to a bug tracker or to the project's homepage, but I don't see one in this case.

There is no rule that a project with a package in a PPA must take bug reports or continue to maintain their package.

Ubuntu uses the infrastructure developed by Debian, and packages follow Debian's rules. Included is a rule that all packages must include a changelog and that they should contain the e-mail for the person responsible for the change.

Assuming you have installed the package you can view `/usr/share/doc/skype-wrapper/changelog` and view the last (top) changelog entry and that entry will give you a possible e-mail address you could use to ask that individual if bug reports are taken and where to send them. For the skype-wrapper package there is only one entry at this time.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, I emailed the author and he told me they manage the bugs from `Github`: https://github.com/sagetarian/skype-wrapper